# Shell sort algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, sorting

Given this Shell sorting algorithm implementation:

```
void shell(float ∗a ,int l ,int r) {
  int i, j, h;
  for ( h = 1 ; 3∗h <= r−l −1; h = 3∗h + 1 );
  for (; h > 0; h / = 3) { // outer loop
    for (i = l+h; i <= r; ++ i) {
      for (j = i; j >= l +h && a[j] < a[j−h]; j −= h) {
        swap (a+j−h , a+ j );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can you analyze it's time complexity in the most simple way?

Given an array of size $n$. I have the following series $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k)$ with $k$ denoting gap of size $1$ to calculate the time complexity of an algorithm of two *for* loops. I want now to add an outer sum to change $k$ with terms of a sequence of gap values. My sequence is the Knuth sequence $S = \frac{3^k-1}{2}$ with max term isn't larger than $\frac{n}{3}$. In code, it is computed this way: `for (h = 1; 3*h +1 <= n-1; h = 3*h + 1);` which means $h \leq \frac{n-2}{3}$. So, I want to sum for all $k \in S = \{1, 4, 13, 40, 121, ...,\}$ with basically something like $\sum \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k) = a \times n^{3/2} + ...$ with the outer sum representing the *for* loop code I included above. For each iteration, I do $k = h$, and then I get the sum, and finally I get the sum of all. how to do that?

I tired the following, but not sure if that s correct:

$\sum \:_{h=1}^{log_3\:\left(\frac{2}{3}n+1\right)}\sum _{k=0}^n\left(n-\left(\frac{3^h-1}{2}+k\right)\right)$

This $h\:\le \:log_3\:\left(\frac{2}{3}n+1\right)$ comes just from the constraint that $\frac{3^h-1}{2} \leq \frac{n}{3}$